# Arduino UNO R3 Plus Digital Pins Overused?

Tags: arduino, led, lcd, button

I have an Arduino UNO R3 Plus with 14 digital pins, but they don't function well. Or maybe they do, but the point is, I think I am overusing them. I have an LCD connected to ports 13-7, 4 LED lights connected to 5-2 and 2 buttons connected to 0-1. But I'm only using one button, so it is technically 1 button connected to port 1. The LED + button is an LED game, and I'm  trying to make the LCD screen a counter for it. The LCD and and the LED "power cords" share the same breadboard segments, the LED is the one going up to the 5V power pin. The problem is that I can only make one work at a time, so I don't know if its the programming or the hardware. So please tell me how I can reprogram/rewire this (or else explain why it is impossible).
[image: Circuit]

My code:

```
int currentLED = 2;
int delayValue = 200;
int numberShown = 0;

#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(13, 12, 10, 9, 8, 7);

void setup() {
    pinMode(1, INPUT); //Button
    pinMode(2, OUTPUT); //White LED
    pinMode(3, OUTPUT); //Yellow LED
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT); //Green LED
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT); //RED LED
    // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows: 
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    // Print a message to the LCD.
    lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

int checkInput() {
  if(digitalRead(1)==0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

}
void loop(){

// set the cursor to column 0, line 1
// (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
// print the number of seconds since reset:
lcd.print(millis()/1000);

  if(digitalRead(1) == 0){
    if(currentLED == 4) {
      digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(4, LOW);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(4, LOW);
      delay(200);
      delayValue = delayValue - 10;
    } else {
      digitalWrite(currentLED, HIGH);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(currentLED, LOW);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(currentLED, HIGH);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(currentLED, LOW);
      delay(200);
    }
  }
  digitalWrite(currentLED, HIGH);
  delay(delayValue);
  digitalWrite(currentLED, LOW);
  delay(delayValue);
  currentLED = currentLED + 1;
  if(currentLED > 5) {
    currentLED = 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Resistor value for the leds? And what are the forward voltages of the led?

Comment: Sorry if I am terrible at electrical engineering, it just fascinates me. But the voltage is 5v for both and the resistor is 330 ohm

Comment: Several  pins on the LCD are miswired.

Comment: The ends of your pot should be connected to supply and ground, and the wiper should be connected to V0.

Comment: Your illustration appears to show a 2 x 16 char LCD display, but the software seems to be treating it as a multiple digit 7 segment display - if it truly is a 2 x 16 LCD, it definitely won't work the way you are trying to drive it.

Comment: @PeterBennett I meant something different, I tried a sketch already made, modified the pins, and still didn't work. But the code has been edited for the LCD, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Assuming you have the leds wired correctly, you have between 9mA and 5mA going to each, which is fine. But your code shows only one will ever be on at any given time. **So what's the actual problem?** The LCD + Arduino + LED(s) are well within the 5v regulator's power range. **Are you using a 9v battery or are you powering it from the wall? What Amperage on the wall wart?**

Comment: There is no reset on the delayValue value at any point, so it's going to very quickly hit zero and below.  Could this be the issue, i.e. there is no delay between on/off, so you can't see anything happening?

Comment: No, the LEDs work fine, the LCD doesn't.

Comment: @RyanGriggs No it can't, that is the point of the game, to see how fast you can press the button when green flashes.

Comment: @Passerby The problem is that I can't figure out how to give power to both.

Comment: @TheKnightsWhoSayNi specific lcd you are using? Are you using a 9v battery? Are you using a dc wall wart/power adapter?

Comment: @Passerby HD44780 comp. 16x2 LCD. I am using a 9v power cable for transferring the code from my computer and a DC battery pack with 3 AA batteries.

Comment: So you are using 4.5v or 9v? Not 5v? Are the batteries fresh? Not all HD44780 lcds are happy with 4.5v or lower. And at that point, you are not getting a regulated 5v from the arduino's regulator...

Comment: I have no idea, the batteries are fresh though.

Comment: @Passerby how can I tell what voltage I am using?

Comment: Use a multimeter.

Answer (score 1):

*NB: I realise this is an old question by now, and should probably be migrated to Arduino SE, but questions without answers are just noise, so I'll plum for an answer..*

> Arduino UNO R3 Plus Digital Pins Overused?

Or to rephrase: Can an Arduino UNO drive both an LCD and series of LEDs together?

The answer is of course a definite yes.. [here's an example of it working](https://github.com/tardate/LittleArduinoProjects/tree/master/playground/HitTheLights).

If the Fritzing diagram in the question can be believed, the primary reason why the circuit was not working as expected is because the LCD is not wired correctly (as pointed out by Ignacio in the comments). In particular, the pot is not doing it's job to adjust contrast, but is pulling RS high.

Fritzing is a good tool, but it is worth getting used to the schematic view. It can make problems like this self-evident, when they are so easy to miss in the breadboard view.